# Lualatex, changebar and latexdiff: no changebars visible

Tags: luatex, latexdiff, changebar

Compiling following latex file with lualatex (0.95) does not show any changebars

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changebar}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{changebar}[1mm]
  \lipsum[2]
  \begin{changebar}[3mm]
    \cbcolor{blue}
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{changebar}
  \cbcolor{red}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{changebar}

\end{document}
```

I stumbled on this when using `git-latexdiff`/`latexdiff`.

It seems to be that the package `changebar` is not developed anymore.

Are there alternative packages for `changebar` which support the upcoming lualatex?

Answer (score 5):

The package hasn't been updated in a while, so it has options to run on emtex from the 1980's but not luatex....

However if you force it to choose `pdftex` option and use the `luatex85` package to emulate pdftex, it seems to work

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\usepackage[pdftex,color]{changebar}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{changebar}[1mm]
  \lipsum[2]
  \begin{changebar}[3mm]
    \cbcolor{blue}
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{changebar}
  \cbcolor{red}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{changebar}

\end{document}
```